# Apache atlas column lineage not found

Tags: hive, apache-atlas

I use Hive2.1.1 and Atlas2.0.0.

I can found table lineage but not found column level lineage

the detailed information is shown below

[image: Table RelationShip]
[image: Table lineage]
[image: Column Info]
[image: No Column lineage]

For debug,

I try Restful first, nothing about column lineage.

```
[root@cent1 bin]# curl -X GET -u admin:admin http://cent1:21000/api/atlas/v2/lineage/27c81b16-b422-4479-84b9-2d643b5dba48
{"baseEntityGuid":"27c81b16-b422-4479-84b9-2d643b5dba48","lineageDirection":"BOTH","lineageDepth":3,"guidEntityMap":{},"relations":[]}
```

I print Kafka msg from `ATLAS_HOOK` topic below:

```
{
"version":{
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "versionParts":[
        1
    ]
},
"msgCompressionKind":"NONE",
"msgSplitIdx":1,
"msgSplitCount":1,
"msgSourceIP":"192.168.10.128",
"msgCreatedBy":"root",
"msgCreationTime":1572687183793,
"message":{
    "type":"ENTITY_CREATE_V2",
    "user":"root",
    "entities":{
        "referredEntities":{
            "-53640556650491":{
                "typeName":"hive_column",
                "attributes":{
                    "owner":"root",
                    "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes.bar@primary",
                    "name":"bar",
                    "comment":null,
                    "position":1,
                    "type":"string",
                    "table":{
                        "guid":"-53640556650488",
                        "typeName":"hive_table",
                        "uniqueAttributes":{
                            "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes@primary"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "guid":"-53640556650491",
                "provenanceType":0,
                "version":0,
                "proxy":false
            },
            "-53640556650492":{
                "typeName":"hive_table",
                "attributes":{
                    "owner":"root",
                    "temporary":false,
                    "lastAccessTime":1572687176000,
                    "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes_create3@primary",
                    "columns":[
                        {
                            "guid":"-53640556650494",
                            "typeName":"hive_column",
                            "uniqueAttributes":{
                                "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes_create3.foo@primary"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "guid":"-53640556650495",
                            "typeName":"hive_column",
                            "uniqueAttributes":{
                                "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes_create3.bar@primary"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "tableType":"MANAGED_TABLE",
                    "sd":{
                        "guid":"-53640556650493",
                        "typeName":"hive_storagedesc",
                        "uniqueAttributes":{
                            "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes_create3@primary_storage"
                        }
                    },
                    "createTime":1572687176000,
                    "name":"pokes_create3",
                    "comment":null,
                    "partitionKeys":[

                    ],
                    "parameters":{
                        "totalSize":"5812",
                        "numRows":"500",
                        "rawDataSize":"5312",
                        "COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE":"{"BASIC_STATS":"true"}",
                        "numFiles":"1",
                        "transient_lastDdlTime":"1572687178"
                    },
                    "db":{
                        "guid":"-53640556650487",
                        "typeName":"hive_db",
                        "uniqueAttributes":{
                            "qualifiedName":"atlas1@primary"
                        }
                    },
                    "retention":0
                },
                "guid":"-53640556650492",
                "provenanceType":0,
                "version":0,
                "proxy":false
            },
            "-53640556650490":{
                "typeName":"hive_column",
                "attributes":{
                    "owner":"root",
                    "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes.foo@primary",
                    "name":"foo",
                    "comment":null,
                    "position":0,
                    "type":"int",
                    "table":{
                        "guid":"-53640556650488",
                        "typeName":"hive_table",
                        "uniqueAttributes":{
                            "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes@primary"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "guid":"-53640556650490",
                "provenanceType":0,
                "version":0,
                "proxy":false
            },
            "-53640556650495":{
                "typeName":"hive_column",
                "attributes":{
                    "owner":"root",
                    "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes_create3.bar@primary",
                    "name":"bar",
                    "comment":null,
                    "position":1,
                    "type":"string",
                    "table":{
                        "guid":"-53640556650492",
                        "typeName":"hive_table",
                        "uniqueAttributes":{
                            "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes_create3@primary"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "guid":"-53640556650495",
                "provenanceType":0,
                "version":0,
                "proxy":false
            },
            "-53640556650493":{
                "typeName":"hive_storagedesc",
                "attributes":{
                    "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes_create3@primary_storage",
                    "storedAsSubDirectories":false,
                    "location":"hdfs://cent1:9000/user/hive/warehouse/atlas1.db/pokes_create3",
                    "compressed":false,
                    "inputFormat":"org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat",
                    "parameters":{

                    },
                    "outputFormat":"org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat",
                    "table":{
                        "guid":"-53640556650492",
                        "typeName":"hive_table",
                        "uniqueAttributes":{
                            "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes_create3@primary"
                        }
                    },
                    "serdeInfo":{
                        "typeName":"hive_serde",
                        "attributes":{
                            "serializationLib":"org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe",
                            "name":null,
                            "parameters":{
                                "serialization.format":"1"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "numBuckets":-1
                },
                "guid":"-53640556650493",
                "provenanceType":0,
                "version":0,
                "proxy":false
            },
            "-53640556650494":{
                "typeName":"hive_column",
                "attributes":{
                    "owner":"root",
                    "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes_create3.foo@primary",
                    "name":"foo",
                    "comment":null,
                    "position":0,
                    "type":"int",
                    "table":{
                        "guid":"-53640556650492",
                        "typeName":"hive_table",
                        "uniqueAttributes":{
                            "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes_create3@primary"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "guid":"-53640556650494",
                "provenanceType":0,
                "version":0,
                "proxy":false
            },
            "-53640556650488":{
                "typeName":"hive_table",
                "attributes":{
                    "owner":"root",
                    "temporary":false,
                    "lastAccessTime":1572663197000,
                    "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes@primary",
                    "columns":[
                        {
                            "guid":"-53640556650490",
                            "typeName":"hive_column",
                            "uniqueAttributes":{
                                "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes.foo@primary"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "guid":"-53640556650491",
                            "typeName":"hive_column",
                            "uniqueAttributes":{
                                "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes.bar@primary"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "tableType":"MANAGED_TABLE",
                    "sd":{
                        "guid":"-53640556650489",
                        "typeName":"hive_storagedesc",
                        "uniqueAttributes":{
                            "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes@primary_storage"
                        }
                    },
                    "createTime":1572663197000,
                    "name":"pokes",
                    "comment":null,
                    "partitionKeys":[

                    ],
                    "parameters":{
                        "transient_lastDdlTime":"1572663225",
                        "totalSize":"5812",
                        "numRows":"0",
                        "rawDataSize":"0",
                        "numFiles":"1"
                    },
                    "db":{
                        "guid":"-53640556650487",
                        "typeName":"hive_db",
                        "uniqueAttributes":{
                            "qualifiedName":"atlas1@primary"
                        }
                    },
                    "retention":0
                },
                "guid":"-53640556650488",
                "provenanceType":0,
                "version":0,
                "proxy":false
            },
            "-53640556650489":{
                "typeName":"hive_storagedesc",
                "attributes":{
                    "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes@primary_storage",
                    "storedAsSubDirectories":false,
                    "location":"hdfs://cent1:9000/user/hive/warehouse/atlas1.db/pokes",
                    "compressed":false,
                    "inputFormat":"org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat",
                    "parameters":{

                    },
                    "outputFormat":"org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat",
                    "table":{
                        "guid":"-53640556650488",
                        "typeName":"hive_table",
                        "uniqueAttributes":{
                            "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes@primary"
                        }
                    },
                    "serdeInfo":{
                        "typeName":"hive_serde",
                        "attributes":{
                            "serializationLib":"org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe",
                            "name":null,
                            "parameters":{
                                "serialization.format":"1"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "numBuckets":-1
                },
                "guid":"-53640556650489",
                "provenanceType":0,
                "version":0,
                "proxy":false
            },
            "-53640556650487":{
                "typeName":"hive_db",
                "attributes":{
                    "owner":"root",
                    "ownerType":"USER",
                    "qualifiedName":"atlas1@primary",
                    "clusterName":"primary",
                    "name":"atlas1",
                    "description":null,
                    "location":"hdfs://cent1:9000/user/hive/warehouse/atlas1.db",
                    "parameters":{

                    }
                },
                "guid":"-53640556650487",
                "provenanceType":0,
                "version":0,
                "proxy":false
            }
        },
        "entities":[
            {
                "typeName":"hive_process",
                "attributes":{
                    "outputs":[
                        {
                            "guid":"-53640556650492",
                            "typeName":"hive_table",
                            "uniqueAttributes":{
                                "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes_create3@primary"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "recentQueries":[
                        "create table pokes_create3 as select foo,bar from pokes"
                    ],
                    "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes_create3@primary:1572687176000",
                    "inputs":[
                        {
                            "guid":"-53640556650488",
                            "typeName":"hive_table",
                            "uniqueAttributes":{
                                "qualifiedName":"atlas1.pokes@primary"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "name":"create table pokes_create3 as select foo,bar from pokes",
                    "queryText":"create table pokes_create3 as select foo,bar from pokes",
                    "operationType":"CREATETABLE_AS_SELECT",
                    "startTime":1572686979104,
                    "queryPlan":"Not Supported",
                    "endTime":1572687183754,
                    "userName":"root",
                    "queryId":"root_20191102172939_5de2901c-49e1-473c-ad2f-7e5f5b3251ee"
                },
                "guid":"-53640556650496",
                "provenanceType":0,
                "version":0,
                "proxy":false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Where is the column lineage? How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to have both of these Hive patches.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13112 released in Hive 2.1.0
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14706 released in hive 2.2.0

As far as I understand, the first patch exposes Lineage information in case of CTAS and the second patch allows atlas plugin to pick it up from the hive hook.

According to the Atlas doc : https://atlas.apache.org/#/HookHive